# Using function's Type Parameter as a token in Jasmine's Testbed.get()

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this:

```
function tasks<T>(testCases: (dependency: T) => void) {
  let d1 = Testbed.get(T);
  testCases(d1);
}
```

With usage like this:

```
it('should create a new user', () => {
 tasks<UserService>(dependency => {
  dependency.createUser();
  // some assertions
 });
});
```

I need to get a typed dependency inside callback function, sadly I am unable to make type token Testbed.get() requires from function's type parameter T. Is there any way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: Is [this FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function) what you are looking for?